# Binomial expansion of $(1+x)^i$ where $i^2 = -1$.

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-theorem

I was reading today about this single variable binomial expansion

$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\ldots$

For example,

$(1+x)^2 = 1+2x+x^2$

However, is it also valid when exponents are imaginary?

$\begin{align*}
(1+x)^i &= 1+ix+\frac{i(i-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{i(i-1)(i-2)}{3!}x^3+\ldots\\\
&= 1+ix+(-1/2 - i/2)x^2+(1/2+i/6)x^3+(-5/12)x^4+(1/3-i/12)x^5+\ldots
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Yes. Actually, that's a way of *defining* $(1+x)^i$. And another thing: I strongly suggest you that you *never* describe $i$ as $\sqrt{-1}$. If you are afreid that your readers do not understand what $i$ is, call it the “imaginary unit”.

Comment: For almost all $x$, $(1+x)^i$ is multi-valued.

Comment: If $n$ is not a positive integer you might want to check convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1+x)^i = e^{i\times\ln(1+x)}$ so it is also equals to $\cos(ln(1+x)+i\times\sin(\ln(1+x))$, where defined. So i left it to you to find the corresponding Taylor series.

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. This is a Mathematics forum, not a programming forum. Use simple juxtaposition, `\cdot` for $\cdot$ or `\times` for $\times$. The symbol $*$ in Mathematics have other uses.

Comment: This looks pretty! What steps were involved to get that final $e^{i\times\ln(1+x)$

Comment: Definition of $a^b$ as $e^{b \cdot \ln(a)}$

Comment: @vengy Use that $b\log a = \log(a^b)$, and $\log$ and $\exp$ are inverses.

Answer (score 3):

This is just like any other Taylor series; the successive coefficients are just successive derivatives evaluated at $x=1$ with $1^i=1$ divided by the appropriate factorials. Since there is a branch cut for $(1+x)^i$ or with any noninteger exponent, you actually get *one branch* of the function, specifically the branch that equals $1$ at $x=0$ and is continuous within the convergence region of the series (see below).

With any exponent at all other than a nonnegative integer, convergence is limited by hitting a singularity, which is at $1+x=0$ or $x=-1$. So you converge in $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

The result was found around 1665 by Isaac Newton in the form of the [Binomial Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$ (1+x)^{\alpha }=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\;{\binom {\alpha }{k}}\;x^{k}=1+\alpha x+{\frac {\alpha (\alpha -1)}{2!}}x^{2}+{\frac {\alpha (\alpha -1)(\alpha -2)}{3!}}x^{3}+\cdots $$

where $ {\binom {\alpha }{k}}:=\frac{1}{k!} {\alpha (\alpha -1)(\alpha -2)\cdots (\alpha -k+1)}$ is the generalized binomial coefficient. This formula holds for any complex $α$ and $|x|<1$. Note that if $α∈ℕ$, then $\binom {\alpha }{k} = 0$ for $k>α$, so in this case it reduces to the regular binomial theorem.